# How to override WindowStyle in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, customization, window-style

Can anyone show me how to override the WindowStyle in WPF application? preferablly in XAML.

I'm writing an application and I want to customize the top bar of the window.
I know I can change it with , but I'm not able to do any customization with it.

Here is a picture of what I'm thinking.
From:

[image]
To:

[image]

I want to be able to change background color and put my own icons on it.

Comment: I used the following tutorial to achive something equivalent [Custom Window Chrome in WPF](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuhhL_NF-B0)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This requires creating the Window chrome (borders) completely from scratch.  For an example, including code, see [WPF Custom Chrome Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/131515/WPF-Custom-Chrome-Library) on CodePlex.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The sample you provided was using C#, is there other version of this is written in VB?

Comment: @Fever Most samples I've seen are C# - you might want to just use an existing library, such as http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 4.5, you can access the `WindowChrome` property of your window. If you are using .NET 3.5 or .NET 4.0, you will need to use a separate library, such as `Microsoft.Windows.Shell.dll`.

If you do not care about the system minimize animation, you can set `ResizeMode` to `NoResize` and `WindowStyle` to `None` then draw your custom border.